# Is React Native solving the right pain point?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, react-native

I read an article about React Native(http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/03/26/react-native-retrospective.html), and I'm also experimenting it at the moment.

During a few days of experiment, my feeling is switching from excited to concerned.

As React Native is focused on V in MVC, but IMHO I'm more keen to share code in M (and Services) across platforms. I'm happy to have native views (xib for iOS and layout for Android), as I think they are meant to be platform specific, and that is the main reason for going native rather than hybrid and HTML5. The story is different for Model and Services though as they are common and better to be shared across platforms.

It might make sense to have shared code between Mobile(React Native) and Web(React), but it is too early to tell now.

How do you think? And I look forward to hearing your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With React Native you *can* write all of your views in Obj-C (Cocoa, XIB or Java) if you want. It's actually not that complicated.

However, some of the greatest strengths of RN is that it uses JavaScript. This allows you to write all of your business logic ("M" as you put it) in JavaScript and now share that across mobile platforms (iOS & Android right now). Of course, if your business logic is decoupled from the UI (as it should be), you can then even share that on the Web as well.

Before this, if you wanted a shared common library of business logic between mobile platforms you had to either write it in C++ or perhaps use something like Xamarin (C#).

I'm not sure if that is answering your question or perhaps agreeing with some of the things you are talking about haha. AFAIK, React Native is definitely solving the right pain point because it's so flexible, it let's you decide *what* that pain point is. :)

Comment: Dave, yes you are right. I'm currently using Xamarin for our mobile  apps, and share a lot of code (in ViewModel, Model, Services). I'm trying to use React Native to do the same, but I found out that communication between React Native and Native is still not that flexible, and also callback is only supported in Native Module, which is called from React Native to Native, not the other way around (events is the option, but still not mature). I will keep exploring and waiting for a while for React Native to get more confidence. Thanks

Comment: You mentioned: "communication between React Native and Native is still not that flexible"...interesting, can you expand upon that a little more?

Comment: hi Dave, what I meant by that is say I want to call React Native functions from within Native code (Objective-C), particularly in cases where I use React Native as ViewModel, and Native code as ViewController. Hope it makes sense.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand what you're saying. In my experience, when working with hybrid apps the best way to introduce React Native at first are just dumb views that you pass data down to. (ie. https://github.com/dsibiski/react-native-hybrid-app-examples/blob/master/iOS/RNEmbeddedAppExample/PassingDataViewController.m#L33-L34).

Comment: Later on, when you want actual functionality moved into RN, you should move it all there and replace the entire native screen or branch in RN. This way, you don't need to "call" any functions in your RN code from the native world. Besides, it's always best to keep everything as "declarative" as possible by just passing down props to your RN views and let those components do their thing, not reaching down and calling functions (if possible).

Comment: Thanks Dave for your advice. We've decided to go with React Native for one of our internal apps, and will start building it shortly, look forward to having interesting things to share with you, cheers.